# Setting innerHTML of nextSibling

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, dom

I have the following HTML:

```
<h3 onclick="replaceNextChild(this);">Some content...</h3>
<div>Div that I am interested in replacing</div>
```

I have the following JavaScript:

```
<script>
function replaceNextChild(element) {

   element.nextSibling.innerHTML = "I replaced the next element in the DOM";
}
</script>
```

Why is it that JavaScript does not replace the next element? I am also using jQuery and wouldn't mind a jQuery solution.

Comment: If you have jQuery loaded, you might as well use it as demonstrated in [@alex's answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7788529/set-innerhtml-of-nextsibling/7788537#7788537). That's sort of the point of having it in the first place. ;)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Because in many browsers, the `nextSibling` will be an empty text node.

Use [`nextElementSibling`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/Element.nextElementSibling) instead.

```
element.nextElementSibling.innerHTML = "I replaced the next element in the DOM";
```

You'll need to create a function for browsers that don't support it.

```
( element.nextElementSibling || nextElementSibling( element ) )
                           .innerHTML = "I replaced the next element in the DOM";

function nextElementSibling( el ) {
    if( el ) {
        while( (el = el.nextSibling) && el.nextSibling.nodeType !== 1 );
        return el;
    }
}
```

Comment: Corrected the code example, it was not correct instead of looking at the nextnode's type it was looking at the type of the node after that (el.nodeType instead of el.nextSibling.nodeType, el is already the next node at that point)

Answer (score 4):

> I am using jQuery so any solutions using methods from that library will be helpful too

Well, that changes it just a tad :P

```
$(this).next().html('I replaced the next element in the DOM');
```

---

Because it is a text node. Set `nodeValue` or `data` instead, if you want to change the text node, otherwise maybe change your function to...

```
function replaceNextChild(element) {

   do {
       element = element.nextSibling;
   } while (element.nodeType != 1);

   element.innerHTML = "I replaced the next element in the DOM";
}
```

[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/MFCaP/).

But really [Patrick's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7788529/set-innerhtml-of-nextsibling/7788538#7788538) (use [`nextElementSibling`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/Element.nextElementSibling) is much better).

Comment: Ah, jQuery is used now. That certainly *does* change things. :)

Comment: +1 great jquery example! I used it as: .....   function replaceNextChild(element) {  $(element).next().html('new content!');}

Answer (score 0):

The nextSibling property returns the node immediately following the specified node, in the same tree level.

The returned node is returned as a Node object.

The difference between this property and nextElementSibling, is that nextSibling returns the next sibling node as an element node, a text node or a comment node, while nextElementSibling returns the next sibling node as an element node (ignores text and comment nodes).

**This property is read-only.**

http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/prop_node_nextsibling.asp